# How can I obfuscate a jar in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, obfuscation

I found out that an executable jar file can be decompiled to retrieve the original source code using [Java Decompiler](http://java-decompiler.github.io/), which allows decompiling and browsing the source with the JD-GUI.

I'm trying to obfuscate a jar file to protect it from retrieving the original source code.

I have tried proguard but sounds a little bit time consuming!!
I then tried IntelliGuard 2 plugin but there was no information about what proguard and yguard and how to use them!!

I read some resources that I need to generate an Ant build file for proguard or yguard to be able to obfuscate the jar file. Then I stuck a little bit on generating a jar file to obfuscate.

**Is there an easy and straightforward way to generate a jar and obfuscate it?**

Comment: Please follow: [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question), so rewrite your question to something like: "How can I obfuscate a jar in IntelliJ", and then answer your own question with the body you currently have. (It should still read like a Q&A)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been trying to obfuscate a jar file to protect it from retrieving the original source code.

Obfuscation in Intellij requires [IntelliGuard 2](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10974-intelliguard-2) plugin and [yuguard 3.0.0](https://github.com/yWorks/yGuard/releases) (preferably [yguard-bundle-3.0.0.zip](https://github.com/yWorks/yGuard/releases/download/3.0.0/yguard-bundle-3.0.0.zip)).

**The obfuscation process :**

1. **Generate Module** out of the project: File --> project settings --> Modules ( + new module and set proper out path)
2. **Generate jar** file using Artifacts: File --> project settings --> Artifacts ( + JAR and naming configuration)
3. [Generate Ant build](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-ant-build-file.html)
4. **Obfuscate the jar** file: File --> project settings --> Facets( + Obfuscation ), then choose the path to ygurad-bundle/lib/yuguard.jar, and choose the main class. See illustrating image below:

[image]

Afterward, build Artifacts (build--> build Artifacts), then Obfuscate the jar file ( build--> obfuscate jar, then choose the input jar and the output obfuscated jar).

I couldn't find another way or resource to follow and do it the easy way, so I decided to share my experience.

Comment: The plugin is crashing in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3, can you please specify your IDE version?